# Cardinality of the set of all TMs that semidecide a r.e. language

Tags: turing-machines

What is the cardinality of the following set

$M: = { \text{M is a Turing Machine with}  \sum_{i}=\text{{0,1} and LA(M)=L}}$
where $ \text{L is a recursively enumerable language such that } L \subseteq \text{{0,1}}*$

Which means how many TMs semidecide a recursively enumerable language L?

We know that the set of all r.e. languages is countably infinite and that we can encode any TM as a binary number, thus as an integer and therefore we can define a bijection from the set of all TMs to $\mathbb N$. Thus, M is countable?

I don't feel like this proof would actually work. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The set of all TMs is countable as you mentioned. Your $M$ is a subset. The proof looks good

Comment: Bonus points for figuring out whether $M$ is *finite* or *countably infinite*.